# Why object that implements an interface cannot be converted to type on service injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm having a problem with injection because `OneSignalClient` cannot be converted to type `IPushNotificationClient<T<TResponse, TModel>>`. `OneSignalClient` implements `IOneSignalClient` and `IOneSignalClient` implements `IPushNotificationClient`. But why it not being converted?

I have this code structured for push notification to be injected like this.

```
services.AddScoped(
        typeof(IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>>),
        f => new OneSignalClient(
            this.Configuration.GetSection("OneSignalSettings")["Endpoint"],
            this.Configuration.GetSection("OneSignalSettings")["AppId"],
            new HttpClientHandler()));
```

And below is the structure.

```
public class OneSignalClient : IOneSignalClient
{
    public OneSignalClient(string apiEndpoint, string appId, IHttpClientHandler httpClient)
    {
        this.CreateNotification = new CreateNotificationEndpoint(apiEndpoint, appId, httpClient);
    }

    public ICreateNotificationEndpoint CreateNotification { get; private set; }
}
public interface IOneSignalClient: IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint>
{
}
public interface ICreateNotificationEndpoint:
    PushNotification.Endpoints.ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>
{
}
public interface IPushNotificationClient<TCreate>
{
    TCreate CreateNotification { get; }
}

//service
public class PushNotificationService : IPushNotificationService{
    private readonly IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>> pnsClient;
    public PushNotificationService(IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>> pnsClient)
    {
      this.pnsClient = pnsClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: A little terminology lesson for your future benefit. A class/struct does not _inherit_ an interface, it implements it.

Comment: Just because two types exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that a generic parameterized over those two types exhibits the *same* relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint>`cannot be converted to `IPushNotificationClient<ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>>`. This is obviously not a match.

But your `ICreateNotificationEndpoint` derives from `ICreateNotificationEndpoint<T>`, which are two different interface Types.

Just decide which interface you want to use at any place you have, don't mix them up.
You are not defining an alias name here.

```
public interface ICreateNotificationEndpoint:
PushNotification.Endpoints.ICreateNotificationEndpoint<CreateNotificationResponse, CreateNotification>
```

This is a new Type definition and makes things incompatible.

Unless you want to try with Covariance or Contravariance, but why making things complicated.